# Dictionary of lists to dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dictionary with each key holding a list of float values. These lists are not of same size.

I'd like to convert this dictionary to a pandas dataframe so that I can perform some analysis functions on the data easily such as (min, max, average, standard deviation, more).

My dictionary looks like this:

```
{
    'key1': [10, 100.1, 0.98, 1.2],
    'key2': [72.5],
    'key3': [1, 5.2, 71.2, 9, 10.11, 12.21, 65, 7]
}
```

What is the best way to get this into a dataframe so that I can utilize [basic functions](https://chrisalbon.com/python/pandas_dataframe_descriptive_stats.html) like `sum`, `mean`, `describe`, `std`?

The examples I find (like the link above), all assume each of the keys have the same number of values in the list.

Comment: What exactly should the output look like? The concept of a DataFrame with variable column heights doesn't really make any sense because the rows have no alignment. There are almost certainly better ways to do what you are trying. Creating separate Series for instance.

Comment: The short answer is: you can't.  If you want statistical functions, you can always use numpy.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

```
d={
    'key1': [10, 100.1, 0.98, 1.2],
    'key2': [72.5],
    'key3': [1, 5.2, 71.2, 9, 10.11, 12.21, 65, 7]
}

df=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d,orient='index').transpose()
```

Then `df` is

```
    key3    key2    key1
0   1.00    72.5    10.00
1   5.20    NaN     100.10
2   71.20   NaN     0.98
3   9.00    NaN     1.20
4   10.11   NaN     NaN
```

Note that numpy has some built in functions that can do calculations ignoring `NaN` values, which may be relevant here. For example, if you want to find the mean of `'key1'` column, you can do it as follows:

```
import numpy as np
np.nanmean(df[['key1']])
28.07
```

Other useful functions include `numpy.nanstd, numpy.nanvar, numpy.nanmedian, numpy.nansum`.

EDIT: Note that the functions from your [basic functions](https://chrisalbon.com/python/pandas_dataframe_descriptive_stats.html) link can also handle `nan` values. However, their estimators may be different from those of numpy. For example, they calculate the [unbiased estimator of sample variance](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/100041/how-exactly-did-statisticians-agree-to-using-n-1-as-the-unbiased-estimator-for), while the numpy version calculates the ["usual" estimator of sample variance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance#Sample_variance).

Answer (score 21):

```
your_dict = {
    'key1': [10, 100.1, 0.98, 1.2],
    'key2': [72.5],
    'key3': [1, 5.2, 71.2, 9, 10.11, 12.21, 65, 7]
}

pd.concat({k: pd.Series(v) for k, v in your_dict.items()})

key1  0     10.00
      1    100.10
      2      0.98
      3      1.20
key2  0     72.50
key3  0      1.00
      1      5.20
      2     71.20
      3      9.00
      4     10.11
      5     12.21
      6     65.00
      7      7.00
dtype: float64
```

Or with `axis=1`

```
your_dict = {
    'key1': [10, 100.1, 0.98, 1.2],
    'key2': [72.5],
    'key3': [1, 5.2, 71.2, 9, 10.11, 12.21, 65, 7]
}

pd.concat({k: pd.Series(v) for k, v in your_dict.items()}, axis=1)

     key1  key2   key3
0   10.00  72.5   1.00
1  100.10   NaN   5.20
2    0.98   NaN  71.20
3    1.20   NaN   9.00
4     NaN   NaN  10.11
5     NaN   NaN  12.21
6     NaN   NaN  65.00
7     NaN   NaN   7.00
```

Comment: does this have the added benefit of making the keys the first column?  Pycharm debugger shows that it is.  `nutrients_totals_df = pd.concat({k:pd.Series(v) for k,v in
                                         nutrients_totals_dict.items()}, axis=1)`

Answer (score 5):

I suggest you just create a dict of Series, since your keys do not have the same number of values:

```
{ key: pd.Series(val) for key, val in x.items() }
```

You can then do Pandas operations on each column individually.

Once you have that, if you really want a DataFrame, you can:

```
pd.DataFrame({ key: pd.Series(val) for key, val in x.items() })

     key1  key2   key3
0   10.00  72.5   1.00
1  100.10   NaN   5.20
2    0.98   NaN  71.20
3    1.20   NaN   9.00
4     NaN   NaN  10.11
5     NaN   NaN  12.21
6     NaN   NaN  65.00
7     NaN   NaN   7.00
```

Answer (score 3):

Use

`df=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d,orient='columns')`

or, as 'orient' is set to 'columns' by default, just use

`df=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d)`

Answer (score 2):

You can:

define the index as

```
idx = counts.keys()
```

then concatenate series

```
df = pd.concat([pd.Series(counts[i]) for i in idx], axis=1).T
```

lastly add the index

```
df.index=idx
```

Comment: This worked great for what I was doing: a dict with a list as values. The only thing that could be added is to rename the columns. Thanks